# What is a good pattern for using multiple strategies one after another that is also extensible

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, factory

I have a class that needs to get some data to perform analysis. Let's say the interface for getting the data is as follows:

```
public interface IDataFetcher
{
   List<someobject> GetData();
}
```

In a very simple case my class will use this interface as follows in one of its methods:

```
void PerformAnalysis(List<IDataFetcher> fetchers)
{
     ...
     foreach(IDataFetcher fetcher in fetchers)
     {
        List<someobject> myList = fetcher.GetData();
        //We will try fetching one by one using different fetchers until we get the data
        if(myList.Count > 0)
           break;
     }
     ...
}
```

Now, different fetching implementations such as fetching from file, fetching from machine or fetching from dB take different input for their data sources e.g. File Fetcher would need the file path, machine fetcher would need machine name and dB fetcher would need database string.

In my case this source information can only be known at runtime (from user input or some other source) later in PerformAnalysis Method above. So, now I cannot pass IDataFetchers since source is not known.

The way I modified this was to *not* perform the instantiation from outside but to defer it by creating an Abstract factory as follows:

```
public interface IDataFetcherAbstractFactory
{
       IDataFetcher CreateFetcher(string source);
}

public interface FileDataFetcherFactory : IDataFetcherAbstractFactory
{
      IDataFetcher CreateFetcher(string source)
      {
            return new FileDataFetcher(source);
      }
}
```

Similary, different fetchers would do the same like MachineDataFetcherFactory etc. 
One implementation of a FileDataFetcher could be swapped with another by updating few tags in Unity Container XML configuration without modifying source code at all. So, this is good.

Now, I updated my method as follows:

```
void PerformAnalysis (List<IDataFetcherAbstractFactory> fetcherFactories)
{
     ...
     string source = GetSource(); //source known dynamically
     foreach(IDataFetcherAbstractFactory factory in fetcherFactories)
     {
        IDataFetcher fetcher = factory.Create(source);
        List<someobject> myList = fetcher.GetData();
        //We will try fetching one by one using different fetchers until we get the data
        if(myList.Count > 0)
           break;
     }
         ...
}
```

a) Is this approach of using Factory correct or is there a better way to do this ?

b) The second issue I observed is for each factory product the source string could be different. i.e. for database factory source string is connection string, for machine its machine name etc. This means my class must be aware of what factory it is dealing with. Is it okay to make it aware ?

c) Without updating the source can a new factory be somehow passed/injected into the fectcherFactories list using unity ?
Example, someone implemented a new WebServiceFetcher : IDataFetcher and a corresponding factory for it. Now, to make my framework utilize it, I will have to modify source code to add it to the list of fetcherFactories. This does not sound scalable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missunderstanding something in your question but I will try to offer an answer:

Declare runtime data for user input values:

```
    public interface IRuntimeData
    {
     string filePath { get; set; }
     string connectionString { get; set; }
     string machineName { get; set; }
    }

    class RuntimeData : IRuntimeData
    {
     public string filePath { get; set; }
     public string connectionString { get; set; }
     public string machineName { get; set; }
    }
```

Declare interface for data fetcher and implementations. Theese classes need IRuntimeData to work.

```
interface IDataFetcher
{
 object getData();
}

class FileFetcher : IDataFetcher
{
 private string _filePath;
 public FileFetcher(IRuntimeData userInputData)
 {
  _filePath = userInputData.filePath;
 }

 public object getData()
 {
  return "Hello from FileFetcher. File path is " + _filePath;
 }
}

class DBFetcher : IDataFetcher
{
 private string _connStr;
 public DBFetcher(IRuntimeData userInputData)
 {
  _connStr = userInputData.connectionString;
 }

 public object getData()
 {
  return "Hello from DBFetcher. Connection string is " + _connStr;
 }
}

class MachineFetcher : IDataFetcher
{
 private string _machineName;
 public MachineFetcher(IRuntimeData userInputData)
 {
  _machineName = userInputData.machineName;
 }

 public object getData()
 {
  return "Hello from MachineFetcher. Machine name is " + _machineName;
 }
}
```

Declare Analyzer class. This class need a list of IDataFetcher.

```
class Analyzer
{
 private List<IDataFetcher> _fetcherList;

 public Analyzer(IDataFetcher[] fetcherList)
 {
  _fetcherList = new List<IDataFetcher>(fetcherList);
 }

 public void PerformAnalysis()
 {
  foreach (IDataFetcher dtFetcher in _fetcherList)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(dtFetcher.getData());
  }
 }
}
```

Now, register Datafetchers in the container at app bootstrap.

```
 IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<IDataFetcher, FileFetcher>("file");
  container.RegisterType<IDataFetcher, DBFetcher>("db");
  container.RegisterType<IDataFetcher, MachineFetcher>("machine");
```

When user insert runtime data, create a instance and register it in the container:

```
IRuntimeData rtData = new RuntimeData();
rtData.connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local)";
rtData.filePath = @"C:\foo.txt";
rtData.machineName = "jlvaqueroMachine";

container.RegisterInstance<IRuntimeData>(rtData);
```

The last part is resolve the Analyzer through container:

```
  Analyzer myAnalyzer = container.Resolve<Analyzer>();
  myAnalyzer.PerformAnalysis();
  Console.Read();
```

And you can see how all DataFetcher registered in the container are created an injected into Analyzer.

Full example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2VANij).

PD: If `RegisterInstance` of runTimeData looks like service locator anti-pattern to you; it is possible to resolve `Analyzer` overriding runtimeData pependency:

```
IRuntimeData rtData = new RuntimeData();
rtData.connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local)";
rtData.filePath = @"C:\foo.txt";
rtData.machineName = "jlvaqueroMachine";

 Analyzer myAnalyzer = container.Resolve<Analyzer>(new DependencyOverride<IRuntimeData>(rtData));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to dotnetfiddle.  That'll come in handy!